# Missing Rep from Upvotes (not daily limit)

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

So this is a bit odd. I down-voted a question because it was vague. The post was then edited to include source code. From that source code I gave an answer, but forgot to revert my down-vote.  In the mean time I got 3 upvotes for my answer, but no rep for them.

I'm not near the rep-limit for either day. Believing I would not be getting rep for an answer to a question I downvoted, I made a quick edit to add a useful tag to the post, and then revert my downvote.

However, I don't have the rep for my answer.

Is this by-design, or will I get the rep eventually?

[My profile:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657476/david-hughes?tab=reputation)

[The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956263/nullreferenceexception-on-valid-operation/15172445#15172445)

Comment: See in the questions [revisions list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14956263/revisions): *made Community Wiki by being edited by more than 5 different editors*. That said, if your answer will get the bounty, you will get the rep just fine.

Comment: Okay thanks. It was a pretty ugly question the first time around. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (and the question) is community wiki. You don't get rep for votes on CW posts.

Comment: Not that the question probably *should* be CW. Seems the "excessive-edits" filter kicked in.

Comment: The question became CW at the 10th revision when it was edited by 5 different users.